# How to make in Cypress an equivalent of PressKeyCode from Appium?

Tags: javascript, appium, cypress

Today i meet a problem with a particular input, it looks like that :

[image] --> [image]

The problem with this input is that it's an input with 6 input in it, so a typical `cy.get('element').type(aValue)` is not working.
I tried to loop on each of the 6 inputs, but it's not working either, the code is here :

```
let charAtValue
for (let i = 0; i < aValue.length; i++) {
    charAtValue = aValue.charAt(i)
    cy.get('element-id-' + i).type(charAtValue, {force: true})
    cy.wait(200)
}
```

It seem that the value are not writed like it should be on other normal input (like a textArea) but it show me a "click" on each input.
You can see it : [image: gif_error]
(This solution : `cy.get('element').invoke('val', aValue)` doesn't work either but it show the number on each input but disappear when i want to validate the entry)

Before using Cypress, i was using Appium and i was just looping like that `driver.pressKeyCode(charValue)` (doc : http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/keys/press-keycode/) over the value (i didn't select any element to press the code like it could be here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and it worked fine.

But right now this solution doesn't work with Cypress. Or i just don't understand how this solution https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/46913 works, i tried different behaviour and nothing worked for my particular case.

Anyone have an idea to overpass this problem with my input or any solution to make the same thing as i did with Appium ?

EDIT : Adding HTML input code.

```
<div class="CodeConfirm_otp rs-flex-box-grid-item rs-flex-box-grid-item-24">
    <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1awozwy r-1777fci">
        <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-uia4a0 r-1kihuf0 r-18u37iz r-1ph75f1 r-sgscqh">
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-109y4c4 r-1udh08x r-92ng3h">
                <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1kihuf0 r-dnmrzs r-bztko3 r-13qz1uu">
                    <div dir="auto"
                         class="css-901oao css-vcwn7f r-z4anl9 r-mbtgtf r-ubezar r-135wba7 r-u8s1d r-1vq8nrm r-eafdt9 r-1clhhh9 r-1wn9b5e"></div>
                    <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-ndvcnb"><input maxlength="6" autocapitalize="sentences" autocomplete="on"
                                                             autocorrect="on" dir="auto" spellcheck="true" type="tel"
                                                             class="css-11aywtz r-1ak1ltj r-qklmqi r-z4anl9 r-1ya47tt r-1i10wst r-1it3c9n r-mabqd8 r-f1odvy r-11c0sde r-1cnnq8j r-15ysp7h r-1exrs8c r-1mdbw0j r-gy4na3 r-vmopo1"
                                                             value=""></div>
                    <div dir="auto" aria-label="undefinedError"
                         class="css-901oao r-1p0dtai r-1h8z911 r-11wrixw r-1mnahxq r-bnwqim r-fdjqy7"
                         data-testid="undefinedError"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-13awgt0">
                <div aria-label="SMSCodeInput" tabindex="0" class="css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1otgn73 r-1i6wzkk r-lrvibr"
                     style="transition-duration: 0s;">
                    <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1kihuf0 r-dnmrzs r-bztko3 r-13qz1uu">
                        <div dir="auto"
                             class="css-901oao css-vcwn7f r-z4anl9 r-mbtgtf r-ubezar r-135wba7 r-u8s1d r-1vq8nrm r-eafdt9 r-1clhhh9 r-1wn9b5e"></div>
                        <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-ndvcnb"><input autocapitalize="sentences" autocomplete="on"
                                                                 autocorrect="on" dir="auto" readonly=""
                                                                 spellcheck="true" inputmode="numeric"
                                                                 class="css-11aywtz r-1jqwq3o r-1ak1ltj r-qklmqi r-z4anl9 r-1ya47tt r-1i10wst r-1it3c9n r-mabqd8 r-f1odvy r-7o8qx1 r-11c0sde r-1cnnq8j r-15ysp7h r-6dt33c r-1exrs8c r-1mdbw0j r-ou255f r-gy4na3 r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-q4m81j"
                                                                 value=""></div>
                        <div dir="auto" aria-label="undefinedError"
                             class="css-901oao r-1p0dtai r-1h8z911 r-11wrixw r-1mnahxq r-bnwqim r-fdjqy7"
                             data-testid="undefinedError"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-13awgt0">
                <div aria-label="SMSCodeInput" tabindex="0" class="css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1otgn73 r-1i6wzkk r-lrvibr"
                     style="transition-duration: 0s;">
                    <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1kihuf0 r-dnmrzs r-bztko3 r-13qz1uu">
                        <div dir="auto"
                             class="css-901oao css-vcwn7f r-z4anl9 r-mbtgtf r-ubezar r-135wba7 r-u8s1d r-1vq8nrm r-eafdt9 r-1clhhh9 r-1wn9b5e"></div>
                        <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-ndvcnb"><input autocapitalize="sentences" autocomplete="on"
                                                                 autocorrect="on" dir="auto" readonly=""
                                                                 spellcheck="true" inputmode="numeric"
                                                                 class="css-11aywtz r-1jqwq3o r-1ak1ltj r-qklmqi r-z4anl9 r-1ya47tt r-1i10wst r-1it3c9n r-mabqd8 r-f1odvy r-7o8qx1 r-11c0sde r-1cnnq8j r-15ysp7h r-6dt33c r-1exrs8c r-1mdbw0j r-ou255f r-gy4na3 r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-q4m81j"
                                                                 value=""></div>
                        <div dir="auto" aria-label="undefinedError"
                             class="css-901oao r-1p0dtai r-1h8z911 r-11wrixw r-1mnahxq r-bnwqim r-fdjqy7"
                             data-testid="undefinedError"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-13awgt0">
                <div aria-label="SMSCodeInput" tabindex="0" class="css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1otgn73 r-1i6wzkk r-lrvibr"
                     style="transition-duration: 0s;">
                    <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1kihuf0 r-dnmrzs r-bztko3 r-13qz1uu">
                        <div dir="auto"
                             class="css-901oao css-vcwn7f r-z4anl9 r-mbtgtf r-ubezar r-135wba7 r-u8s1d r-1vq8nrm r-eafdt9 r-1clhhh9 r-1wn9b5e"></div>
                        <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-ndvcnb"><input autocapitalize="sentences" autocomplete="on"
                                                                 autocorrect="on" dir="auto" readonly=""
                                                                 spellcheck="true" inputmode="numeric"
                                                                 class="css-11aywtz r-1jqwq3o r-1ak1ltj r-qklmqi r-z4anl9 r-1ya47tt r-1i10wst r-1it3c9n r-mabqd8 r-f1odvy r-7o8qx1 r-11c0sde r-1cnnq8j r-15ysp7h r-6dt33c r-1exrs8c r-1mdbw0j r-ou255f r-gy4na3 r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-q4m81j"
                                                                 value=""></div>
                        <div dir="auto" aria-label="undefinedError"
                             class="css-901oao r-1p0dtai r-1h8z911 r-11wrixw r-1mnahxq r-bnwqim r-fdjqy7"
                             data-testid="undefinedError"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-13awgt0">
                <div aria-label="SMSCodeInput" tabindex="0" class="css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1otgn73 r-1i6wzkk r-lrvibr"
                     style="transition-duration: 0s;">
                    <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1kihuf0 r-dnmrzs r-bztko3 r-13qz1uu">
                        <div dir="auto"
                             class="css-901oao css-vcwn7f r-z4anl9 r-mbtgtf r-ubezar r-135wba7 r-u8s1d r-1vq8nrm r-eafdt9 r-1clhhh9 r-1wn9b5e"></div>
                        <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-ndvcnb"><input autocapitalize="sentences" autocomplete="on"
                                                                 autocorrect="on" dir="auto" readonly=""
                                                                 spellcheck="true" inputmode="numeric"
                                                                 class="css-11aywtz r-1jqwq3o r-1ak1ltj r-qklmqi r-z4anl9 r-1ya47tt r-1i10wst r-1it3c9n r-mabqd8 r-f1odvy r-7o8qx1 r-11c0sde r-1cnnq8j r-15ysp7h r-6dt33c r-1exrs8c r-1mdbw0j r-ou255f r-gy4na3 r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-q4m81j"
                                                                 value=""></div>
                        <div dir="auto" aria-label="undefinedError"
                             class="css-901oao r-1p0dtai r-1h8z911 r-11wrixw r-1mnahxq r-bnwqim r-fdjqy7"
                             data-testid="undefinedError"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-13awgt0">
                <div aria-label="SMSCodeInput" tabindex="0" class="css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1otgn73 r-1i6wzkk r-lrvibr"
                     style="transition-duration: 0s;">
                    <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1kihuf0 r-dnmrzs r-bztko3 r-13qz1uu">
                        <div dir="auto"
                             class="css-901oao css-vcwn7f r-z4anl9 r-mbtgtf r-ubezar r-135wba7 r-u8s1d r-1vq8nrm r-eafdt9 r-1clhhh9 r-1wn9b5e"></div>
                        <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-ndvcnb"><input autocapitalize="sentences" autocomplete="on"
                                                                 autocorrect="on" dir="auto" readonly=""
                                                                 spellcheck="true" inputmode="numeric"
                                                                 class="css-11aywtz r-1jqwq3o r-1ak1ltj r-qklmqi r-z4anl9 r-1ya47tt r-1i10wst r-1it3c9n r-mabqd8 r-f1odvy r-7o8qx1 r-11c0sde r-1cnnq8j r-15ysp7h r-6dt33c r-1exrs8c r-1mdbw0j r-ou255f r-gy4na3 r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-q4m81j"
                                                                 value=""></div>
                        <div dir="auto" aria-label="undefinedError"
                             class="css-901oao r-1p0dtai r-1h8z911 r-11wrixw r-1mnahxq r-bnwqim r-fdjqy7"
                             data-testid="undefinedError"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-13awgt0">
                <div aria-label="SMSCodeInput" tabindex="0" class="css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1otgn73 r-1i6wzkk r-lrvibr"
                     style="transition-duration: 0s;">
                    <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1kihuf0 r-dnmrzs r-bztko3 r-13qz1uu">
                        <div dir="auto"
                             class="css-901oao css-vcwn7f r-z4anl9 r-mbtgtf r-ubezar r-135wba7 r-u8s1d r-1vq8nrm r-eafdt9 r-1clhhh9 r-1wn9b5e"></div>
                        <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-ndvcnb"><input autocapitalize="sentences" autocomplete="on"
                                                                 autocorrect="on" dir="auto" readonly=""
                                                                 spellcheck="true" inputmode="numeric"
                                                                 class="css-11aywtz r-1jqwq3o r-1ak1ltj r-qklmqi r-z4anl9 r-1ya47tt r-1i10wst r-1it3c9n r-mabqd8 r-f1odvy r-7o8qx1 r-11c0sde r-1cnnq8j r-15ysp7h r-6dt33c r-1exrs8c r-1mdbw0j r-ou255f r-gy4na3 r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-q4m81j"
                                                                 value=""></div>
                        <div dir="auto" aria-label="undefinedError"
                             class="css-901oao r-1p0dtai r-1h8z911 r-11wrixw r-1mnahxq r-bnwqim r-fdjqy7"
                             data-testid="undefinedError"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the code you've used to loop through with cypress?

Comment: @agoff i added a code sample.

Comment: Can you post the full HTML for the input fields? My thinking is that if there is some way to identify _all_ of the elements at once, we could use `cy.each()` to iterate through those elements, instead of a `for` loop outside of cypress' chain

Comment: @agoff I added the html code of the input.

Comment: Thanks! I've been able to come up with a possible solution :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes from your `for` loop not being a part of the Cypress chain, and the code executing at different times. Instead, if you can grab each of the input fields, you can iterate through them and use the provided index to type in each one. Something like the following could work:

```js
const inputText = '123456'
cy.get('[aria-label="SMSCodeInput"]').each((inputField, inputIndex) => {
  cy.wrap(inputField).find('input').type(inputText.charAt(inputIndex), {force: true});
});
```

Additionally, if you could add a custom attribute on each input field, that could simplify it:

```js
const inputText = '123456'
cy.get('[custom-Attr="input"]').each((inputField, inputIndex) => {
  cy.wrap(inputField).type(inputText.charAt(inputIndex));
});
```

Comment: Hello @agoff, your solution do the same thing as my `for` loop.
Here is what is happening (make a gif) : https://ibb.co/1vDn5cH.

If you don't want to click on the link, i added the gif on the ticket.

For your recommendation about adding custom attribute, I can't do it right now, but it's planned in the future, thanks for the reminder!.

Comment: Hmm... if you just try to get the first element, will it type? I think there might be something going on that Cypress just can't type into your `input` elements....